# Utility to open a browser and click on specific link

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

i have to create a utility which will open the browser of specific site and click on specific hyperlink which is present in that page.
i am creating one console app with below code

```
try
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("MyURL.aspx");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

can someone help how to click on a specific link which is present in the above page?

i dont want to use any third party tool, is something can be done using existing .net libraries?

Comment: You could use [WatiN](http://watin.org/) to automate your browser of choice.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, using `WatiN` will make that easier:

```
using(var browser = new IE())
{
    browser.GoTo("url");
}
```

To click on a specific link:

```
browser.Link(Find.ById("someId")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a go on the HTML agility pack which attaches the DOM to a super node, and where you can query the subsequent noeds - e.g. links.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any external tool then for Internet Explorer it can be done easily  using SHDocVw library. Here is a small example to open a google page and click on 'Sign in' link.

```
SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
ie.Visible = true;
ie.Navigate("https://www.google.co.in");
//Wait for page to load
while (ie.Busy) 
{
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
}
dynamic allLinks = ((mshtml.IHTMLDocument3)ie.Document).getElementsByTagName("a");
foreach (mshtml.IHTMLAnchorElement link in allLinks) {
    //Do some validation to find out the required link
    if (link.href.Contains("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin")) {
        link.click();
    }
}
```